# Custom Log4j file name

Tags: java, log4j

My log4j file name is log4j2.xml 
I need to customize the file name like log4j2-A.xml, log4j2-B.xml and read into application. How it can be done?

Answer (score 3):

[Log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#config_location) says this...

> **How do I specify the configuration file location?**
>
> By default, Log4j looks for a configuration file named log4j2.xml (not
>   log4j.xml) in the classpath.
>
> You can also specify the full path of the configuration file with this
>   system property: -Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml
>
> That property can also be included in a classpath resource file named
>   log4j2.component.properties.
>
> Web applications can specify the Log4j configuration file location
>   with a servlet context parameter. See [this section](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html#ContextParams) of the Using Log4j
>   2 in Web Applications manual page.